# Cross compiling Wireshark to ARM using GCC and Clang

Tags: linux, gcc, cmake, arm, cross-compiling

I had been trying to compile wireshark to ARM with both GCC and Clang for a while now and could not sort out the error. Following is the exact error when I invoke cmake command with toolchain file.

```
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for one of the modules 'glib-2.0'
-- Found GLIB2: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so (found suitable version "2.48.2", minimum required is "2.32.0") 
-- Checking for module 'gmodule-2.0'
-- Found gmodule-2.0, version 2.48.2
-- Could NOT find GMODULE2 (missing:  GMODULE2_LIBRARY) 
-- Checking for module 'gthread-2.0'
-- Found gthread-2.0, version 2.48.2
   CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 
  (message):
  Could NOT find GTHREAD2 (missing: GTHREAD2_LIBRARY)
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/modules/FindGTHREAD2.cmake:38 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:1028 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

As you could see I have already install the gmodule2.0 and it still complains that GMODULE2_LIBRARY is missing. I tried searching a lot but could not fix the issue. This happen when I try to compile with Clang too. Following is the contents of my toolchain file.

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(tools /usr)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${tools}/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)
```

Is there anything I should add on the toolchain file?

P.S I also tried to compile apache2 and there also same kind of error occured stating that cmake could not find `lua51` libraries regardless of that being installed.

Comment: You want to check the cmake log.

Comment: CMakeError.log does not have any build errors. According to the output the error is something related to inability to find GTHREAD2 and GMODULE2